# Python | SpeechRecognition error

Tags: python, pyaudio, google-speech-recognition

Всем привет, у меня есть код

```
import speech_recognition
def record_and_recognize_audio(*args: tuple):
    """
    Запись и распознавание аудио
    """
    with microphone:
        recognized_data = ""

        # регулирование уровня окружающего шума
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(microphone, duration=2)

        try:
            print("Listening...")
            audio = recognizer.listen(microphone, 5, 5)

        except speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError:
            print("Can you check if your microphone is on, please?")
            return

        # использование online-распознавания через Google 
        try:
            print("Started recognition...")
            recognized_data = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="ru").lower()

        except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
            pass

        # в случае проблем с доступом в Интернет происходит выброс ошибки
        except speech_recognition.RequestError:
            print("Check your Internet Connection, please")

        return recognized_data
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # инициализация инструментов распознавания и ввода речи
    recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
    microphone = speech_recognition.Microphone()

    while True:
        # старт записи речи с последующим выводом распознанной речи 
        voice_input = record_and_recognize_audio()
        print(voice_input)
```

однако после его выполнения выводит ошибку(

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\VSC\Voise Migle Dog\main.py", line 37,
in <module>
    microphone = speech_recognition.Microphone()
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "C:\Users\ilyas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio;
check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

Comment: Ну так установите pyaudio

Comment: check installation, Вот же вам интерпретатор выдал